# How to prevent intents bypassing lockscreen

Tags: android

I was building a custom passcode based lockscreen application. I found out that user can easily bypass the lockscreen and unlock the phone by clicking on any of the notification.

Is there a way to intercept these intents (started via notification) and force user to enter the passcode before unlocking and continuing with the intent?